# JavaScript "if"-statement not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, time, logic

I'm having the strangest problem right now; This if-statement below should run the console.log("It's night!") when the currentHour is between 22 and 07, but for some reason it doesn't!

```
console.log("hello");
console.log(currentHour);
if (currentHour >= 22 && currentHour <= 7) {console.log("Its night!");};
```

Console output:

> hello 
> 22

So the if-statement is not run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If current hour is HIGHER/equal than 22 AND LOWER/equal than seven will never be true.

What you probably want:

```
if(currentHour >= 22 || currentHour <=7)
```

Comment: Ah of course! Sometimes you get a little code-blind :D